# Mocha js test =>correct output in debug mode , in normal mode the output is different

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

```
describe('#My Test'){
var responseBody;
it('getting the response from service' , (done)=>{
request(paramsForHittingAPI ,(error , response , body)={
responseBody = body;
done();
);
);

it('Database validation' , (done)=>{
var promise = fuctionReturningPromiseContainingResultFromDatabaseOutput;
promise.done(function(result){
console.log(result.length);
console.log(responseBody.length);
done();
},function(error){
    done();
);
});
}
```

when running  output is 
10 , 
251

when debugging output is 
251 , 
251

Database result is different when debugging as compared to when running in normal mode
command used is npn test
Also Please let me know how can i debug it in chrome (specific command )

Comment: Well, your first problem is that none of what you posted is valid code. I'm guessing you pulled this from your actual tests, but then edited for here? Show us the real tests, because this code has lots of syntax errors.

Comment: (Also, you'll need to show us the actual code your testing, there's no way we can know what the problem is otherwise.)

Comment: please modify the sample code from snippet. send us a gist, jsfiddle or something: https://gist.github.com/sombriks/e09df1b3b91e9181757467d29cdbc1bc